# Returning value of id column of every n-th row in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I need to process the `id` column (primary key, integer) of a table with millions of records (about 25M). However, i am only interested in every n-th id.

Currently a simple approach is used:

```
select id from big order by id;
```

and then every n-th id is processed by the client software (cursor based).

I was wondering if this could not be much more efficient, if the selection of every n-th id is delegated to postgresql. Tried this one:

```
select id from 
    (select id, row_number() over (order by id) from big) _ 
    where row_number % 10000 = 0;`
```

However, this approach is *much* slower:

```
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on _  (cost=0.44..1291886.20 rows=115413 width=4) (actual time=9.385..10731.994 rows=2308 loops=1)
   Filter: ((_.row_number % '10000'::bigint) = 0)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 23080220
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.44..945648.28 rows=23082528 width=12) (actual time=0.107..9450.396 rows=23082528 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using big_pkey on big  (cost=0.44..599410.36 rows=23082528 width=4) (actual time=0.093..2403.921 rows=23082528 loops=1)
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.172 ms
 Execution Time: 10732.229 ms
(8 rows)
```

The simple query has an execution time of 2721.101 ms (so almost 4 times faster).

Question: is there a better way to do this? (using PostgreSQL 11)

Comment: You do realize that for processing data in chunks you should use a cursor [DECLARE/FETCH/CLOSE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-fetch.html) instead?

Comment: Please elaborate. I do not understand how this can approve the query itself.

Comment: I meant that instead of trying to improve the query itself you should evaluate what do you need the query for. It looks like maybe you want to just retrieve the data from the table in chunks of 10000 to avoid using up too much memory. This is not the right approach for this though.

The problem is that the query itself as defined is not possible to improve dramatically - it will need to retrieve those millions of rows discarding 99.99%, which will bite you when the required index would not be in cache.

Maybe relaxing the specs, like for example retrieving every about 10000 rows, can help.

Comment: @Tometzky Clear now. Yes, this is a good comment. I try to improve this feature "from both sides".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a cursor and fetch only every tenth row (also works for different intervals):

```
BEGIN; -- must be in a transaction

DECLARE cc CURSOR FOR
   SELECT id FROM big ORDER BY id;

/* skip 9 rows */
MOVE 9 IN cc;

FETCH NEXT FROM cc;
```

Continue performing the `MOVE` and `FETCH` in a loop until you run out of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the nth ID for sampling, or is there some other reason that it must be the actual nth in a sorted result?

If all you need is a random sample, TABLESAMPLE is great. All you have to do is add a simple clause to your SELECT and, depending on what you want, a LIMIT.

Here's a recent question with more details:

[I need a function to select 88 random rows from a table (without duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454021/i-need-a-function-to-select-88-random-rows-from-a-table-without-duplicates/57455672#57455672)

Comment: No, it cannot be a random sample. Thanks anyway.